# Choose multiple text files from file manager

Tags: android

I have one edit text. I want to pick multiple files and read them and write to the edit text (I want to concat multiple files and show in edit text). Currently, I can pick only a single file from the file manager, and there is no problem.

I tried many of the StackOverflow suggestions but there is no of use.

this is for picking the single file from the file manager.

```
if (id == R.id.actionOpen) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Speech Data/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"), PICK_FILE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String fileContent = readTextFile(uri);
            vocalText.setText(fileContent);
        }
    }
}

private String readTextFile(Uri uri) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Place this in onActivityResult**

```
if(null != data.getClipData()) { // checking multiple selection or not
         for(int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
            Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
         }
      } else {
         Uri uri = data.getData();
      }
```

Comment: I don't want to pick any images or any kind of media files. I want to pick multiple text files. please, give me a suggestion for this.

Comment: have you tried.. pls try once its worked .. to get multiple images or videos or files...

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Still, it's picking an only single file

Comment: intent.setType("*/*");
        String[] extraMimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/doc"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
try with

Comment: Still facing the same issue.